# Cannot establish local S3 uploads with refinerycms

Tags: amazon-s3, refinerycms, fog

I've set ENV variables in application.rb

```
ENV['S3_KEY']='key'
ENV['S3_SECRET']='secret'
ENV['S3_BUCKET']='myapp-development'
```

I've added the 'fog' gem to my Gemfile

```
gem 'fog'
```

I've got this added to the very end of development.rb

```
Refinery::Core.config.s3_backend = true
```

And, experimentally, I've also added my S3 key and secret to my bash_profile:

```
export S3_KEY=key
export S3_SECRET=secret
```

Regardless, when I upload files they don't go to my S3 bucket, and are (I assume) stored locally. Here's the log action for uploading a file:

```
Started POST "/refinery/images?dialog=true" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-27 19:07:46 -0400
Processing by Refinery::Admin::ImagesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bofz2fukPA6e/olwZ2zXlkdj/apaxZ69aZnh6xSGkT4=", "image"=>{"image"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f9d54045c60 @original_filename="4.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image[image][]\"; filename=\"4.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/zv/h2w4bghn3gj_5t9ws6x7s6r40000gn/T/RackMultipart20120427-36682-ptku7o>>]}, "wymeditor"=>"", "modal"=>"true", "dialog"=>"true", "app_dialog"=>"true", "field"=>"", "update_image"=>"", "thumbnail"=>"", "callback"=>"", "conditions"=>"", "locale"=>:en}
  Refinery::Role Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "refinery_roles".* FROM "refinery_roles" WHERE "refinery_roles"."title" = 'Refinery' LIMIT 1
  Refinery::User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "refinery_users".* FROM "refinery_users" INNER JOIN "refinery_roles_users" ON "refinery_users"."id" = "refinery_roles_users"."user_id" WHERE "refinery_roles_users"."role_id" = 1
  Refinery::User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "refinery_users".* FROM "refinery_users" WHERE "refinery_users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Refinery::UserPlugin Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "refinery_user_plugins".* FROM "refinery_user_plugins" WHERE "refinery_user_plugins"."user_id" = 1 ORDER BY position ASC
  Refinery::Role Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "refinery_roles".* FROM "refinery_roles" INNER JOIN "refinery_roles_users" ON "refinery_roles"."id" = "refinery_roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "refinery_roles_users"."user_id" = 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (3.1ms)  INSERT INTO "refinery_images" ("created_at", "image_ext", "image_height", "image_mime_type", "image_name", "image_size", "image_uid", "image_width", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Fri, 27 Apr 2012 23:07:47 UTC +00:00], ["image_ext", nil], ["image_height", 320], ["image_mime_type", "image/jpeg"], ["image_name", "4.jpeg"], ["image_size", 46220], ["image_uid", "2012/04/27/19/07/47/673/4.jpeg"], ["image_width", 480], ["updated_at", Fri, 27 Apr 2012 23:07:47 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered text template within layouts/refinery/admin_dialog (0.0ms)
  Rendered refinery/_html_tag.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/anonymouscoward/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@refinerycms/gems/refinerycms-core-2.0.3/app/views/refinery/admin/_dialog_success.html.erb (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1127ms (Views: 99.4ms | ActiveRecord: 6.7ms)
cache: [GET /refinery/images/new?app_dialog=true&dialog=true] miss
cache: [GET /refinery/images/new?app_dialog=true&dialog=true] miss


Started GET "/refinery/images/new?app_dialog=true&dialog=true" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-27 19:07:47 -0400
Processing by Refinery::Admin::ImagesController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"app_dialog"=>"true", "dialog"=>"true", "locale"=>:en}
  Refinery::Role Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "refinery_roles".* FROM "refinery_roles" WHERE "refinery_roles"."title" = 'Refinery' LIMIT 1
  Refinery::User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "refinery_users".* FROM "refinery_users" INNER JOIN "refinery_roles_users" ON "refinery_users"."id" = "refinery_roles_users"."user_id" WHERE "refinery_roles_users"."role_id" = 1
  Refinery::User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "refinery_users".* FROM "refinery_users" WHERE "refinery_users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Refinery::UserPlugin Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "refinery_user_plugins".* FROM "refinery_user_plugins" WHERE "refinery_user_plugins"."user_id" = 1 ORDER BY position ASC
  Refinery::Role Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "refinery_roles".* FROM "refinery_roles" INNER JOIN "refinery_roles_users" ON "refinery_roles"."id" = "refinery_roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "refinery_roles_users"."user_id" = 1
  Rendered /Users/anonymouscoward/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@refinerycms/gems/refinerycms-core-2.0.3/app/views/refinery/admin/_error_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/anonymouscoward/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@refinerycms/gems/refinerycms-core-2.0.3/app/views/refinery/admin/_form_actions.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/anonymouscoward/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@refinerycms/gems/refinerycms-images-2.0.3/app/views/refinery/admin/images/_form.html.erb (13.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/anonymouscoward/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@refinerycms/gems/refinerycms-images-2.0.3/app/views/refinery/admin/images/new.html.erb within layouts/refinery/admin_dialog (16.9ms)
  Rendered refinery/_html_tag.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/anonymouscoward/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@refinerycms/gems/refinerycms-core-2.0.3/app/views/refinery/admin/_javascripts.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/anonymouscoward/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@refinerycms/gems/refinerycms-core-2.0.3/app/views/refinery/admin/_head.html.erb (9.9ms)
  Rendered refinery/_message.html.erb (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 64ms (Views: 49.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)
[2012-04-27 19:07:47] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer
  /Users/anonymouscoward/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `eof?'
  /Users/anonymouscoward/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in `run'
  /Users/anonymouscoward/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
cache: [GET /refinery/images?_=1335568067618] miss
cache: [GET /refinery/images?_=1335568067618] miss


Started GET "/refinery/images?_=1335568067618" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-27 19:07:47 -0400
Processing by Refinery::Admin::ImagesController#index as */*
  Parameters: {"_"=>"1335568067618", "locale"=>:en}
  Refinery::Role Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "refinery_roles".* FROM "refinery_roles" WHERE "refinery_roles"."title" = 'Refinery' LIMIT 1
  Refinery::User Load (3.0ms)  SELECT "refinery_users".* FROM "refinery_users" INNER JOIN "refinery_roles_users" ON "refinery_users"."id" = "refinery_roles_users"."user_id" WHERE "refinery_roles_users"."role_id" = 1
  Refinery::User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "refinery_users".* FROM "refinery_users" WHERE "refinery_users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Refinery::UserPlugin Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "refinery_user_plugins".* FROM "refinery_user_plugins" WHERE "refinery_user_plugins"."user_id" = 1 ORDER BY position ASC
  Refinery::Role Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "refinery_roles".* FROM "refinery_roles" INNER JOIN "refinery_roles_users" ON "refinery_roles"."id" = "refinery_roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "refinery_roles_users"."user_id" = 1
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "refinery_images" 
  Refinery::Image Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "refinery_images".* FROM "refinery_images" ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
  Rendered /Users/anonymouscoward/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@refinerycms/gems/refinerycms-images-2.0.3/app/views/refinery/admin/images/_grid_view.html.erb (11.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/anonymouscoward/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@refinerycms/gems/refinerycms-images-2.0.3/app/views/refinery/admin/images/_images.html.erb (40.6ms)
  Rendered text template within layouts/refinery/flash (0.0ms)
  Rendered refinery/_message.html.erb (1.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 96ms (Views: 11.3ms | ActiveRecord: 7.6ms)
cache: [GET /system/images/BAhbB1sHOgZmSSIjMjAxMi8wNC8yNy8xOS8wNy80Ny82NzMvNC5qcGVnBjoGRVRbCDoGcDoKdGh1bWJJIg4xMzV4MTM1I2MGOwZU/4.jpeg] miss, store
cache: [GET /system/images/BAhbB1sHOgZmSSIjMjAxMi8wNC8yNy8xOS8wNy80Ny82NzMvNC5qcGVnBjoGRVRbCDoGcDoKdGh1bWJJIg4xMzV4MTM1I2MGOwZU/4.jpeg] miss, store


Started GET "/system/images/BAhbB1sHOgZmSSIjMjAxMi8wNC8yNy8xOS8wNy80Ny82NzMvNC5qcGVnBjoGRVRbCDoGcDoKdGh1bWJJIg4xMzV4MTM1I2MGOwZU/4.jpeg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-27 19:07:47 -0400
cache: [GET /assets/refinery/icons/application_edit.png] stale, valid, store
cache: [GET /assets/refinery/icons/application_edit.png] stale, valid, store


Started GET "/assets/refinery/icons/application_edit.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-27 19:07:48 -0400
Served asset /refinery/icons/application_edit.png - 304 Not Modified (10ms)
[2012-04-27 19:07:48] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
cache: [GET /assets/refinery/icons/accept.png] stale, valid, store
cache: [GET /assets/refinery/icons/accept.png] stale, valid, store


Started GET "/assets/refinery/icons/accept.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-27 19:07:48 -0400
Served asset /refinery/icons/accept.png - 304 Not Modified (8ms)
[2012-04-27 19:07:48] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
cache: [GET /assets/refinery/icons/eye.png] stale, valid, store
cache: [GET /assets/refinery/icons/eye.png] stale, valid, store


Started GET "/assets/refinery/icons/eye.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-27 19:07:48 -0400
Served asset /refinery/icons/eye.png - 304 Not Modified (8ms)
[2012-04-27 19:07:48] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
cache: [GET /assets/refinery/icons/delete.png] stale, valid, store
cache: [GET /assets/refinery/icons/delete.png] stale, valid, store


Started GET "/assets/refinery/icons/delete.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-27 19:07:48 -0400
Served asset /refinery/icons/delete.png - 304 Not Modified (5ms)
[2012-04-27 19:07:48] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a few things. The first thing is to fire up a console and make sure that your ENV variables are all set properly once Rails has loaded. I don't think that's the issue, but it's a good diagnostic to check first.

Second, while you're in the console, check the value of `Refinery::Core.s3_backend`. Does it return true? It may be that putting this statement in your `development.rb` file is causing it to be overwritten when `config/initializers/refinery/core.rb` is being run. This is probably where you should be setting the value of s3_backend anyway.